# Moving Averages (?) Question

Tags: average

I can't figure this out, Im building a basic formula and need some help
Lets say I have three photos, each with a score

1. Photo one: votesCount = 3 [9,8,7]
2. Photo two: votesCount = 5 [9,8,1,6,7]
3. Photo three: votesCount = 1 [4]

I want to create a reference to cumulativeScore that is a moving average of sorts where I will be able to simply use the cumulative average, the new score, and the total count (or count of photos ideally) to calculate a rough average score.

Is this possible? The photos dont have references to themselves, so I cannot use individual averages int he equation, nor the individual scores. I could use individual vote counts, but that would be a cumulativeVotes variable, not indivudal votes..

this is for a demo app im building, all help apprecaited with the maths :)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  I am not sure what you are asking ... Can you maybe extend your example and tell us what you are trying to do with those numbers ... And what kind of averages you are trying to calculate?

Comment: You have not described what you want clearly enough for anybody to help.  What output would you like for each of your three photos?  What does "the photos don't have references to themselves" mean?